# Por que não pode declarar uma variável dentro de um case?

Tags: c, c++, switch, escopo-de-variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Por que isso não compila?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int valor = 0;
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    switch (valor) {
    case 0:
        int variavel = 1;
        printf("%d", variavel);
        break;
    default:
        int variavel = 2;
        printf("%d", variavel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Um engano muito comum é as pessoas acharem que o `case` é um bloco de comandos e gera um novo escopo. Na verdade o `case` é apenas um *label*. Então é apenas um nome para um endereço do código usado para provocar um desvio. Na verdade um `switch` é apenas um `goto` baseado em um valor.

Isto já funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int valor = 0;
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    switch (valor) {
    case 0: {
        int variavel = 1;
        printf("%d", variavel);
        break;
    } default: {
        int variavel = 2;
        printf("%d", variavel);
    }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7EvBQr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gvdamhjz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/VarInCase.c).

As chaves criam um bloco e um escopo, aí pode criar as variáveis.