# Qual a vantagem de usar labels no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**Usando label no `for`**

```js
let str = '';

loop1:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    if (i === 1) {
        continue loop1;
    }

    str = str + i;
}

console.log(str);
```

**Não usando label no `for`**

```js
let str = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    if (i != 1) {
        str = str + i;
    }
}

console.log(str);
```

Nos dois exemplos ambos os códigos fazem a mesma coisa usar um ou outro vai retornar o mesmo resultado, neste exemplo existe alguma vantagem em utilizá-lo, pois no meu ver ao fazer de uso dele o código fica mais longo e caso o programa seja extenso ele irá dificultar a leitura do código. Não só nestes simples exemplos, mas em outros casos quais às vantagens em utilizá-lo. Conheço outras linguagens que possuem em suas entranhas os *label* e `goto` inplementados e os mesmos são iguais do JavaScript? (visto que o JavaScript não possui o comando `goto`, mas o comando `continue` meio que "substitui" ele).

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que é um label em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/462566/o-que-%c3%a9-um-label-em-c)

Answer (score 0):

Labels não são exclusividade do JavaScript, eles são comuns a linguagens com características procedurais, como C, Java, etc.

Quando aplicado a um único loop (um `for` ou um `while` por exemplo) ele não é vantajoso, mas quando você tem dois ou mais loops aninhados, isto é, com um dentro do outro, ele serve para diferenciar para qual dos loops ele quer pular com um `break`, `continue` ou comando similar.

Exemplo: se você der ao loop mais externo o label `primeiro_loop`, poderá dentro dos loops chamar `break primeiro_loop;` para pular para fora de todos os loops de uma vez (se não indicar o label, ele sai somente do loop mais interno e cai dentro do próximo loop).